# Is it a bad idea to run a python script and fetch its output via PHP?

Tags: php, python

I am using php to run a python script and fetching its output using json.dump and showing on my php page. I feel its slower than when I run it through python idle.

Comment: You need to tell us why you want to do this instead of simply running the script.

Comment: I am building a website where I need some output from a python code. I am using php for it as I am not so well-versed with Flask or Django.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly it's no surprise that it feels slower because calling your Python script from PHP, instead of calling it from CLI, increases the operations your PC has to execute. Consider this: first PHP has to create a shell to call your script, then wait for it to finish (e.g. wait for an exit code appearing in the buffer), grab everything from the buffer and then push it into the output buffer and then flush the output buffer, so the data is actually displayed on your page. And besides all of that your output data is transported twice, first from Python to PHP and then from PHP to your browser.

Furthermore, the processing speed depends on the method you use to call your Python script - there are a couple of ways to achieve this and some have more overhead than others.

Comment: That is right. I think one more reason could be that I was using print(json.dump(list_name)), the print statement is another overhead which is increasing execution time. Can I do it without print?

Comment: Just skip the JSON dump and use the output directly. Here's how I do it (allows for background processing and interactive shells):
`$f = trim(\`mktemp\`); passthru($cmd . ($show_output ? " | tee $f" : " > $f") . ($run_in_background ? ' &' : '')); return $run_in_background ? $f : trim(\`cat $f ; rm -rf $f\`);`

The trick here is to write the output of the command to a temporary file and then read that file. If you don't need background processing or interactive shells you can simply do: `$res = \`python3 myscript.py;\`` and in your Python script just use `print`.

Comment: You're welcome :) Minor mistake, btw, it has to be `$res = \`python3 myscript.py\`;`. If you feel it answered your question, please mark it as the accepted answer, so others can see that there is a 'solution'.